# Let $ABC$ be a isosceles triangle ($AC=BC$). Points $D$ are on $AC$ and $E$ is on $BC$...

Tags: geometry

[image]
Let $ABC$ be a isosceles triangle ($AC=BC$). Points $D$ are on $AC$ and $E$ is on $BC$. The intersection of the angle bisectors of $ADE$ and $BED$ is in point $F$. If $F$ belongs to the edge $AB$, prove that it's the midpoint of the edge $AB$.

I think that we have to prove that $AF$ is an altitude of the triangle $ABC$ (since it's an isosceles triangle). I'm just not sure how to do it. I've tried drawing up new altitudes from points $C$ and $B$, respectively, but I've not gotten any significant results. I've also tried calculating angles and looking for a cyclic quadrilateral but nothing's yielded results, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the point on $AC$ such that $FP$ is perpendicular to $AC$.

Let $Q$ be the point on $BC$ such that $FQ$ is perpendicular to $BC$.

Let $R$ be the point on $DE$ such that $FR$ is perpendicular to $DE$.

Since $FD$ is the angle bisector of $\angle ADE$, we have $|FP| = |FR|$. Similarly $|FQ| = |FR|$.

Thus we have $|FP| = |FQ|$. Also $\angle A = \angle B$ and $\angle APF = 90^\circ = \angle BQF$, therefore the two triangles $\triangle APF$ and $\triangle BQF$ are congruent, which implies that $|AF| = |BF|$.

Comment: @Cookie I removed the usage of resp. (which meant "respectively").